# Alternative to \asteraccent

Tags: symbols, unicode-math, mathematics

`\asteraccent` is great. It allows me to put an asterisk above a symbol ([see here](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf))

But, it requires me to use the following package

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

which gives me a terrible time to produce a buggy sty out of its sources and worse than that I have to replace Latex compiler by XeLatex.

All just for `\asteraccent`!

Is there any alternative to `\asteraccent` with a **decent** look?

Comment: I prefer to avoid something like $_x^*$

Comment: `\usepackage{accents}` and `\accentset{*}{a}` maybe?

Comment: @clemens, It is fantastic

Comment: possible duplicate: [Math mode accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177000/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user clemens,

```
\usepackage{accents}


\accentset{*}{a}
```