# czech language with mathrm and mathbb fonts

Tags: pdftex, languages, mathbb, mathrm

How do I use fonts
`\mathrm` and `\mathbb` with czech letters č,ě,š,ř,ž,ý,á,í....?

Command Line:   `bibtex.exe "ideje"`

```
[12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17]

Package amsfonts Warning: Obsolete command \frak; \mathfrak should be used inst
ead on input line 501.

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\ueuf.fd) [18]

LaTeX Warning: Command \v invalid in math mode on input line 529.

! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.529   \item to tam musíš $ně
                                 kde$ použít
? 

! Emergency stop.
\add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
                                                  #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
l.529   \item to tam musíš $ně
                                 kde$ použít


Process has been killed ...
```

Comment: Use `$n\check{e} kde$` instead. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177000/134574

Comment: The question is whether you really want math mode here? 'někde' looks more like a word to me that should be set in normal text mode and not a math formula (`n \cdot \check{e} \cdot k \cdot d \cdot e`?) especially in the context it is presented in. Do you maybe just want to emphasise or highlight the word with italics? Then `\emph{někde}`  would be *much* more appropriate. `$...$` is really only for maths, not for text emphasis. (Compare the output of `\emph{foo}` and `$foo$`)

Comment: What I want is \mathbb. Your \check command doesn't yield a good output: to tam musíš $\mathbb{n\check{e}kde}$ použít

Comment: The standard `\mathbb` font only has glyphs for uppercase characters. Lower-case `\mathbb` is not included. You'd need a different font. But even then math mode is not really suitable for normal text or emphasis of normal text.

Comment: OK. I'm a beginner. How do I make normal text in emphasis mode?

Comment: If you just want to get '*někde*' instead of 'někde', then write `\emph{někde}`.

Comment: This yields italic. What I want is bold.

Comment: Then `\textbf{někde}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Math mode is not suitable to put emphasis or other formatting on normal text. Math mode is (as the name suggests) for mathematics. In particular `$někde$` (if it compiled) or `$n\check{e}kde$` (which compiles, as suggested by  Phelype Oleinik in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478437/czech-language-with-mathrm-and-mathbb-fonts/478448#comment1208341_478437)) would usually be interpreted as a mathematical term, specifically the product of the variables *n*, *ě* (or *e-check*), *k*, *d* and *e*.

Compare

```
$this is horrible emphasis$
```

with

```
\emph{this is emphasis}
```

In particular the mathematics fonts used in TeX may not support the same sets of glyphs with the same accents as the text fonts. (And math accents may be input and handled differently.)

In text there are a variety of ways to emphasise or highlight certain words. A good overview can be found in Nicola Talbot's *LaTeX for Complete Novices* https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/fontstyle.html#44113

```
\documentclass[czech]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
$this is horrible emphasis$ % don't try this at home!

\emph{this is emphasis}

\begin{itemize}
  \item to tam musíš někde použít
  \item to tam musíš \emph{někde} použít
  \item to tam musíš \textit{někde} použít
  \item to tam musíš \textbf{někde} použít
  \item to tam musíš \textsf{někde} použít
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: "to tam musíš někde použít" with different emphasis on 'někde'. First no emphasis, then \emph (italics), then italics, bold and finally sans serif]

---

To answer the question in the title. The standard `amssymb` fonts for `\mathbb` only support upper-case letters (ASCII letters, that is). You would need an alternative that does have lowercase letters (and more importantly and even less likely, you would have to find one that supports properly accented letters). Lowercase letters are not supported. See for example [Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488/35864)

Answer (score 1):

After repeating the same reservations that you should be sure you really want to do this, here’s how you can.

In `unicode-math`, you can set the `\mathrm` font.  If what you want to do is define a Czech word as an operator or variable name, you might prefer setting the operator font and using `\operatorname` from the `amsmath` package.

Unicode does not have any codepoints for accented blackboard bold, but you can declare your own double-struck font face that does.  Here, I use the free font Foglihten No01.

A contrived example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman Caps}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % For example
% Available at http://www.glukfonts.pl/font.php?font=FoglihtenNo01
\setmathfontface\mathds{FoglihtenNo01.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
to tam musíš \(\mathrm{ně kde}\) \\
použít \(\mathds{Ě}\)

\end{document}
```

[image: Czech in mathematics]

Or for a more dramatic contrast:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman Caps}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % For example
% Available at http://www.glukfonts.pl
\setmathfontface\mathds{FoglihtenNo03.otf}[Scale=1.3]

\begin{document}
to tam musíš \(\mathrm{někde}\) \\
použít \(\mathds{Ě}\)

\end{document}
```

[image: Foglihten Noo3 sample]

If what you want are accents over `\mathbb` characters, you can define that as a math accent.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lmodern}{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\caron}{\mathord}{lmodern}{"07}

\begin{document}
R \(\caron{\mathbb{R}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Legacy font sample]