# Problem with accentuation in the math environment

Tags: complexity

Hello I'm using the complexity package to write a text where I would like to highlight some complexity classes.

However the text is being written in a Latin language which requires the use of accents in some words. When I try to make a newfunc using a word as an example, for example, "difícil" the "í" vanished.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Support Icelandic Characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Support Icelandic Characters
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table, xcdraw, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont = {bf}, labelsep = period}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}P{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[a4paper,
  portuguese,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  linktocpage,
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage{complexity}
\newfunc{\dificil}{difícil}


\begin{document}
    problemas $\NP\text{-}\dificil$
\end{document}
```

I would like to know how I make the letter "i" appear accented in the math environment.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Math mode accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177000/math-mode-accents)

Comment: you should always make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @O'Neil No, it doesn't. Try with `dif\acute{i}cil` and you'll see why. Please, vote for reopening.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this will change the font when I try to use it.

Comment: And I updated the example.

Comment: [Use `\imath`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Math_mode): `dif\acute{\imath}cil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `complexity` does is to use a sans serif font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{complexity}

\newcommand{\newtextfunc}[2]{%
  \newfunc{#1}{\textnormal{\sffamily#2}}%
}
\newtextfunc{\dificil}{difícil}
\newtextfunc{\NPdificil}{NP-difícil}

\begin{document}

\dificil\ and \NPdificil

$\dificil\ne\NPdificil$

\end{document}
```

[image]