# How to add a shorter bar under or over a letter in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

I am reading Apostol's Calculus, the upper and lower integrals appear with a shorter bar

[image: upper and lower integrals with a bar]

but this is not the case for `\overline` and `\underline`, the following pic was typeset with `\overline` and `\underline`

[image: typset with \overline and \underline]

but this has two problems:

1. the bar over letter I is too long, so is the bar under the letter I
2. since the letter I is oblique, the bar doesn't move with the letter.

so, is there a way to typeset the upper and lower integrals as same as the book?

Comment: You probably want `\bar` and `\underbar`.  Examples of math accents are shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177000

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, `\bar` is ok for me. but I have to find some definition for `\underbar`, here is it `\newcommand\munderbar[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}`. Thanks.